# runas: I can't invoke system commands

Tags: windows, command-line, runas

This works:

```
$ C:\Users\Guest> runas /user:Administrator cmd
```

Executes a new `cmd.exe` process/window as `Administrator`

However using commands like `type`, `cd`, `echo`, `dir`, etc won't work:

```
$ C:\Users\Guest> runas /user:Administrator type
$ C:\Users\Guest> runas /user:Administrator cd
$ C:\Users\Guest>
$ C:\Users\Guest> echo "hello" > test
$ C:\Users\Guest> runas /user:Administrator "type C:\Users\Guest\test"
```

all of the above give the same error:

```
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - type C:\Users\Guest\test
2: The system can not find the file specified
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `type` and `cd` are internal commands of the command interpreter, `cmd.exe`.

Use

```
$ C:\Users\Guest> runas /user:Administrator "cmd /c type \"C:\Users\Guest\test\""
```

You could call the `cd` command the same way, but there is no point calling `cd` in a process that will terminate immediately.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to use `cd` in this way: `RUNAS /user:Administrator "CMD /K CD C:\Users\Administrator"` however it spawns a new shell that way

Comment: That is the purpose of the `/K` option and the only reason to use a `CD` command, because the shell process doesn't exit immediately.